# How to define a common interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define a payload with different forms of interface in one function.

Each payload is as follows and I have defined the "UpdatePayload" interface as follows:

```
/*
ex) payload interface
const interface updateBodyPayload = {
  title: ...
  content: ...
}
*/

/*
ex) payload interface
const interface updateStatePayload = {
  type: ..
  count: ..
}
*/

// Payload Merge interface
export type updatePayload = Partial<updateBodyPayload | updateStatePayload>;
```

However, the code inside the function produces the following error:

```
// function.ts
const exec = (body: updatePayload) => {
  const { title, content, type, count } = body;
  // -> property 'title', ... does not exists on type updatePayload
}
```

What did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make `updatePayload` type what is result of merging form `updateBodyPayload` and `updateStatePayload`, then it must be like: (`&` instead of `|`)

```
type updatePayload = Partial<updateBodyPayload & updateStatePayload>;
```

Now `updatePayload` will be like:

```
type updatePayload = {
  title?: string;
  content?: string;
  type?: string;
  count?: number;
}
```